# Coded ui - Excel onlineapps - Not able to find a control in offlice online app

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Need help in identifying the excel online controls which dont have unique properties. Here is my scenario:

1) I am trying to automate the application built on SharePoint and Office Online . When I inspect the element it is returning the controls with the div class name(which is shared across all the controls) and style (with width and height which is variable). I am ﻿not finding any unique property to identify the control(Highlighted the control-last control in the below image, I am trying to find):attached is the image of control properties(Div Class):

﻿﻿[Div Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7HNi.png)

Please help me with the sample code (I need to change the value of 50% on runtime)

Comment: HtmlDiv hdiv = new HtmlDiv(brw.FindDivWithId("m_excelWebRenderer_ewaCtl_sheetContentDiv_Flow_0"));  HtmlDiv hchild = new HtmlDiv(hdiv);
 hdiv.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id, "gridRows");
            hdiv.DrawHighlight();
            hchild.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Class, "ewr-nglr");
 UITestControlCollection collection = hchild.FindMatchingControls();
 foreach (UITestControl test in collection)
 {HtmlDiv at = new HtmlDiv(hchild);                 at.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.ClassName, "cv-nwr ewr-vab");

Comment: I am trying to see if I can highlight the cell which has the divId but it is not recognizing the element